# (React API) How to gather data from an array of Context, given the rules of hook and loops?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

This is an issue about [the rules of hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and loops.

I've got an array of Context `ctxArray` and a simple hook `useCustomContext= (idx:number)=>useContext(ctxArray[idx])`
that works well for what I want to do.

The reason I have an array of Context is that my page has a dynamic number of identical components, each with lots of data and nested components (so using context make sense). I can't change the component (legacy code, limited dev time).

Instead of using one giant context, I have split it into multiple contexts for performance. It also improves code clarity.

But now I need to gather the data from my `ctxArray` and I don't know how to do it, since, rule of hook, I can't use hooks in a loop.

Even if I were to write a custom hook, that wouldn't change the issue, since the loop would still be there.

Any idea ?

Comment: An explanation is needed on why exactly do you need to have an array of contexts. That's not how React applications are supposed to be written.

Comment: added
I've got a page with a dynamic amount of identical components.
This component has many fields with an important depth, so using context is appropriate here.

For the sake of the question, let's assume I can't change this component because of reasons out of my control (legacy code and limited amount of time)